# Prevent files from being backed up to iCloud

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I want to save file to the `Document` folder and i don't want iCloud will backing it up, so i saw i can use this method:

```
- (BOOL)addSkipBackupAttributeToItemAtURL:(NSURL *)URL

{
assert([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath: [URL path]]);



NSError *error = nil;

BOOL success = [URL setResourceValue: [NSNumber numberWithBool: YES]

                              forKey: NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey error: &error];

if(!success){

    NSLog(@"Error excluding %@ from backup %@", [URL lastPathComponent], error);

}

return success;

}
```

And i want to ask if i need to call it every time i create new file in the `Document` Folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you create a file or folder that should not be backed up, write the data to the file and then call this method, passing in a URL to the file.
Instead of it, you can call this method for Document folder itself only once.